# Allowing only alphanumeric characters in a form textbox with Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the easiest way to allow the user to only input a-z, 0-9 and spaces in a text field on a form within Bootstrap? I don't want the user for example to be able to type in symbols or code or anything like that.

Comment: this Q is currently sitting with no accepted answers, so it isn't really benefitting the SO community in any way. Connor, any chance you can give some feedback, even if to assert the two answers so far are no good? Arguably this question could be a dupe of a more-generic 'regexp input mask' question and rather than leave it unanswered it might make sense to find a dupe into which to merge it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use https://github.com/ruoso/jquery-regex-mask-plugin with my Bootstrap-styled forms. It works well!

I cannot remember exactly why, but I have cut it down to just this:

```
$.fn.regexMask = function(mask) {
    $(this).keypress(function (event) {
        if (!event.charCode) return true;
        var part1 = this.value.substring(0, this.selectionStart);
        var part2 = this.value.substring(this.selectionEnd, this.value.length);
        if (!mask.test(part1 + String.fromCharCode(event.charCode) + part2))
            return false;
    });
};
```

You could then apply it to your inputs using:

```
var mask = new RegExp('^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$')
$("input").regexMask(mask)
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/nqvsngd3/

Comment: So can you apply the mask to a specific textbox input with a certain ID?

Comment: yep, you could do that using a standard jQuery selector like `$("#my_input_id_here").regexMask(mask)` and that will work on just that textbox.

Comment: Works well, thanks. But it doesn't handle pasting invalid characters into the field. How can this be changed to handle those as well?

Comment: Use jquery .change() as your event handler. You'll need slightly different logic, because you'll have to iterate the pasted chars. match them against your regex, and strip the invalid ones.

Answer (score 6):

You can combine HTML5 pattern validation to prevent users from submitting invalid data:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$" />
```

Because the `pattern` is only validated during form submit, you have to add a small JS function to validate the pattern already during text input:

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'keypress', ':input[pattern]', function( ev ) {
    var regex  = new RegExp( $(this).attr( 'pattern' ) );
    var newVal = $(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(!ev.charCode ? ev.which : ev.charCode);

    if ( regex.test( newVal ) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        ev.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
} );
```

This jQuery snippet will automatically validate the input pattern of all input fields on your page.

**Note**: Not all patterns can be validated during input!
For example `pattern="^[0-9]{4}$"` (a 4-digit number) cannot be validated during input, because your first keypress will enter a 1-digit number, before you enter the second digit, etc.

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#name').keypress(function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z_\. ]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            return true;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use html native pattern attribute on input.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
Country code: <input type="text" name="country_code" 
pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$" title="A-Z a-z 0-9 ' '">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

check at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

also, a useful site: http://html5pattern.com/

Comment: This solution does not limit the values that can be entered into the input field. Rather the form will validate the field right before submitting it. The OP asked for a way to prevent users from even entering invalid characters in the first place...